# Samsung Recovery Solution 4: can I make a Windows disc?

Tags: windows-7

This might seem obvious, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

My computer didn't come with any install discs. Instead, it comes pre-installed with Samsung Recovery Solution 4. This enables you to make a System Software Backup disc, which "enables backing up of the system software to another storage device".

You can also do a "Complete backup", which in my case is 14GB, so 4 DVDs. This means "you can easily restore your computer to the current status using the backup image".

All I want is a Windows 7 install disc so I can reinstall Windows in case I mess up the partitions installing Linux. Neither of these options seems to allow me to do this. Anyone know of a way to make a straight Windows 7 install disc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have an install code (Usually at the bottom of your laptop), you can use a regular Windows 7 installer disk that has the same version as the one you are currently using. Borrow it from someone or download it somewhere... Just install Windows 7 using that disk and input your own install code when it asks for it.

Comment: Also, there are plenty of tools floating around the Internet with which you can extract your Windows product key from the registry in the event that it's not printed on your machine somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know any good places to download a Windows 7 iso?

Comment: I've now found a source for Windows 7 install discs: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/04/28/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/

Now I've reinstalled Windows and got rid of all the useless partitions and bloatware Samsung forced on me. Thanks!